# ObjectSet.AddObject(T) problem?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1, objectset

The ObjectSet.Single(predicate) doesn't work (the Where() and  toList() methods as well) unless i write it this way:

```
ObjectSet.Cast<TEntity>().Single<TEntity>(predicate)
```

But i don't know what to do to resolve the problem with the AddObject and DeleteObject methods:

```
public void Add<TEntity>(TEntity entity)
    {
        ObjectSet.AddObject(entity);
    }
```

The error message tells me that "entity" is a wrong argument. Is the problem related to EF 4.1?

Comment: Can you show an example of the code in use? I think knowing what you are passing in as the predicate is important in order to understand the issue.

Comment: I didn't pass any predicate in yet. The method is underlined red after i finish writing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few snippets from my generic repository:

```
public void Add<K>(K entity) where K : class
{            
    context.CreateObjectSet<K>().AddObject(entity);
}

public K SingleOrDefault<K>(Expression<Func<K, bool>> predicate) where K : class
{
    K entity = context.CreateObjectSet<K>().SingleOrDefault<K>(predicate);

    return entity;
}
```

Please see the link below:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd382944.aspx

**Edit:**  If you already have a created ObjectSet then your class already defines TEntity, therefor your method should be adjusted as such:

```
public void Add(TEntity entity)
{
    ObjectSet.AddObject(entity);
}
```

You should also be able to make similar adjustment to your Single() method, there should be no need for a cast.

Comment: Understood, adjust your Add method to use TEntity as defined by the class template.  You don't need the <TEntity> right after the method name.